DIY Visual Studio Extension: Using Start and Start Without Debugging
I'm creating my own Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Extension (Community VSIX Project), which adds a new emulator to Visual Studio Projects' development environments. Technically this means adding new options under the Start box (ONLY IN SOME PROJECTS!) and why not automatically select one of those (new) options depending on what my extension currently wants. My extension must also support the Start Without Debugging button (right from that Start box) which will start the selected value in the Start box without debugging.
I think that technically if a user clicks the Start box, then the value inside it is sent to my extension's code or my extension listens to that event. Clicking Start Without Debugging would do the same but with info that now Without Debugging is clicked, not the box.
I got some GUID, GuidID and CmdID etc. values from these buttons with VSIPDebugging but I don't have any idea at all how to use these values in my code or in my Command Table.vsct.

Hi , could i confirm with you that your question is how to listen to events like clicking start box through GuidID and CmdID ?

Maybe, I am pretty sure about that is at least one method.

I guess VS should provide relevant API to achieve it. Try to read API to find. Will update if there is new progress.
